# Opening notebook immediately produces error message

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, kernel-startup

Whenever I open the file I get the following as an error

> ReplaceAll::reps: {Sol} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

but as soon as I hit shift+enter the errors go away and the code runs as intended.

Here's a condensed form of the code:

```
ks = 100 ;
kd = 10;
g = 9.81; 
l = 0.1;
Sol = NDSolve[{

xab'[t] == xbb[t],
yab'[t] == ybb[t],
xbb'[t] == -ks*(1 - (l/((xab[t] - 0)^2 + (yab[t] - 0)^2)^(.5)))*(xab[t] - 0)-ks*(1 - (l/((xab[t])^2 + (yab[t])^2)^(.5)))*(xab[t]) - kd*(xbb[t] - 0) - kd*(xbb[t]),
ybb'[t] ==  -ks*(1 - (l/((xab[t] - 0)^2 + (yab[t] - 0)^2)^(.5)))*(yab[t] - 0) - ks*(1 - (l/((xab[t])^2 + (yab[t])^2)^(.5)))*(yab[t]) - kd*(ybb[t] - 0) - kd*(ybb[t] - g),

xab[0] == 0.1, yab[0] ==  0, xbb[0] == 0, ybb[0] == 0},

{xab, xbb, yab, ybb}, {t, 0, 100}];

Manipulate[
ListLinePlot[{{0, 0}, {Part[xab[t] /. Sol, 1], 
Part[yab[t] /. Sol, 1]}, {1.2, 0}},
PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {1, -10}}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Grey, Thick], PlotTheme -> "Detailed"], {t, 
0, 10}]
```

I used to have Evaluate within the Manipulate command, but read that these errors occur because mathematica is trying to evaluate the function symbollically and then numerically, but I'm still getting an error and not sure why?

Comment: You're most likely getting this error because the *visible* manipulate is evaluated instantly but it doesn't have `Sol` because, for this, you first need to evaluate the `NDSolve` calculation. Check out the option `SaveDefinition` of `Manipulate`.

Comment: Awesome, I just used this and it worked well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the solving of `NDSolve` to the initialization so that when Manipulate runs, it has the `sol` value.

In addition, you can't use `t` as slider variable and also use it for the solution of ODE in `NDSolve`. So I changed that. There are other issues you have, but at least this get rid of the error you mentioned

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[
  {{0, 0}, {Part[(xab[t] /. sol) /. t -> t0, 1], 
    Part[(yab[t] /. sol) /. t -> t0, 1]}, {1.2, 0}},
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {1, -10}},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thick],
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed"],
 {t0, 0, 10}, (*changed from t to t0 so not conflict*)

 Initialization :>
  (
   ks = 100;
   kd = 10;
   g = 9.81;
   l = 0.1;
   sol = NDSolve[{xab'[t] == xbb[t], yab'[t] == ybb[t], 
      xbb'[t] == -ks*(1 - (l/((xab[t] - 0)^2 + (yab[t] - 
                   0)^2)^(.5)))*(xab[t] - 0) - 
        ks*(1 - (l/((xab[t])^2 + (yab[t])^2)^(.5)))*(xab[t]) - 
        kd*(xbb[t] - 0) - kd*(xbb[t]), 
      ybb'[t] == -ks*(1 - (l/((xab[t] - 0)^2 + (yab[t] - 
                   0)^2)^(.5)))*(yab[t] - 0) - 
        ks*(1 - (l/((xab[t])^2 + (yab[t])^2)^(.5)))*(yab[t]) - 
        kd*(ybb[t] - 0) - kd*(ybb[t] - g), xab[0] == 0.1, yab[0] == 0,
       xbb[0] == 0, ybb[0] == 0}, {xab, xbb, yab, ybb}, {t, 0, 100}]
   )
 ]
```

Comment: Hmmm, so I know this works, but is there a way to do it where I can use other functions with sol such as plot?  When I try, it looks like it only works with that one function, manipulate.

Comment: @c12uel yes you can. `sol` actually is global. From any other cell, just type `sol` and you'll see it is there. So you can use `sol` from outside Manipulate.   The variables inside the initialization section as they are in above, are actually all global variables.